# VS2015 Illegal tables in compressed metadata stream

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

We're experimenting with upgrading from Visual Studio 2012 to 2015.  The only error we ran into was

> xyzRenamed.dll could not be opened -- Illegal tables in compressed
>   metadata stream.

We've been using this customer-supplied api dll in 2012 for a couple years without any trouble.  Does anyone have any idea why 2015 would be unhappy with the dll while 2012 worked fine?  Any way to avoid it?

Answer (score 7):

It is likely that one of your DLL is obfuscated, specifically by a FOSS project called [Confuser Ex](https://yck1509.github.io/ConfuserEx/). That project can be used in Visual Studio (as an addon) to obfuscate your code. When using that tool, you have a choice of protection layers. You can use some or all the layers. The protection that creates invalid metadata in the compiled DLL is the one that is creating this odd error.

**You can deactivate the invalid metadata protection when generating the obfuscated dll in VS settings at [VisualStudio->Tools->Settings->ConfuserEx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6ab6.png).**

In case you did not create the library, you need to investigate further, maybe use something else than Visual Studio 2015 to compile the project.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.

Comment: True that, it was a bit minimalistic. Added some context and explanations.

Answer (score 2):

Remove

```
<protection id="invalid metadata" />
```

line from CRPROJ file.

Comment: Thanks. This should be helpful for those that have the source for their obfuscated library.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the customer had obfuscated their DLL by an invalid metadata tactic.  Specifically, they were using ConfuserEx. This seems to work fine with VS2012, but VS2015 wasn't having it.  Here is a bug report at ConfuserEx regarding the issue and it was basically deemed as expected behavior.  https://github.com/yck1509/ConfuserEx/issues/313

We were able to get them to rebuild the DLL without this type of obfuscation and it worked fine.

I'm currently unaware of any way we could have modified our VS solution to make use of the obfuscated file. If you know of a way then please post it for others that aren't lucky enough to be able to acquire a non-obfuscated version of their dependency.